# How do I install Rundeck from source (i.e., the github repo)?

Tags: gradle, grails, makefile, installation, rundeck

I am trying to install Rundeck from source.  I have tried three different distributions of Linux (a Debian, Red Hat, and SUSE distribution).  All have had failures.  I install the make command, Java and Git before proceeding.  The "make" command is what fails on every distribution of Linux that I have tried.  The "./gradlew build" command was no more successful either.

I then run these commands:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck.git
mv rundeck /opt/
cd /opt/rundeck
make
```

I always get a failure.  I tried Java 8 and Java 11.  But the problem happens with either.

Here is the error I see on a Debian distribution:

```
Task :core:javadoc
/opt/rundeck/core/src/main/java/com/dtolabs/rundeck/plugins/jobs/JobOptionImpl.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
    static private String produceValuesList(JobOptionImplBuilder builder) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class JobOptionImplBuilder
  location: class JobOptionImpl
1 error

> Task :core:javadoc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:javadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): '/opt/rundeck/core/build/tmp/javadoc/javadoc.options'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s
18 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 16 up-to-date

...
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'rundeckapp/build/libs/rundeck-3.2.7-SNAPSHOT.war' failed
make: *** [rundeckapp/build/libs/rundeck-3.2.7-SNAPSHOT.war] Error 1
```

Here is what I see on a Red Hat derivative:

> sudo ./gradlew build
>
> > Configure project : Building version 3.2.7-SNAPSHOT
> >
> > Task :rundeckapp:grails-spa:runNpmBuild FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':rundeckapp:grails-spa:runNpmBuild'.
>
>   > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 5.0. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s 71 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 65 up-to-date

Here is what I see on Linux SUSE:

> > Task :rundeckapp:grails-spa:runNpmBuild FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':rundeckapp:grails-spa:runNpmBuild'.
>
>   > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                                         option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 5.0. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s 59 actionable tasks: 59 executed
>
> make: *** [Makefile:34:
>   rundeckapp/build/libs/rundeck-3.2.7-SNAPSHOT.war] Error 1

I expect the "make" command to not fail.  I tried installing npm too, but that did not help.  How do I install Rundeck from source?  Which distribution of Linux would be easiest for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your issue and I saw the same error, you need to install the npm package, it works on Ubuntu 20.04 with the following steps:

1. Install npm:

```sh
sudo apt-get install npm
```

2. Install nodejs:

```sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
```

3. Download the Rundeck source code from GitHub:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck
```

4. Build Rundeck following these steps:

```sh
cd rundeck
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build -x test -x integrationTest
```

5. You'll see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzs7K.jpg). The WAR file is located at: `rundeck/rundeckapp/build/libs/`

Comment: You don't need to do #3.  Later you are using `gradlew` (which is recommended) so there isn't any reason to install Gradle.

Comment: Why are you installing Maven in step 1?

Comment: Your `git fetch origin` isn't going to do anything except fetch changes that happened after you cloned the repo and cd'd into the directory and even if something is committed in that time window, fething them won't have any effect on the build unless you merge those changes into your current branch, which your instructions don't suggest.  `fetch` just gets the changes.  `pull` will `fetch` them and `merge` them.

Comment: You're right @JeffScottBrown, answer fixed. I placed that considering a development setup. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are cloning the repo in step #3 and step #4.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks again @JeffScottBrown