# Rundeck - How to use a different JDBC driver - RHEL RPM install

Tags: rundeck

The RedHat RPM install of Rundeck runs it as an executable WAR file. The JDBC driver for SQL server is inside the WAR and is quite old.

How to we use a newer/different SQL Server JDBC driver than what is in the WAR?

Version 3 of Rundeck "expanded" to the filesystem (didn't run from a WAR) and we were able to put the drivers in Rundeck's "lib" folder, but in this case we don't feel like adding it to the WAR and then modifying the MANIFEST.MF inside the WAR to add it to the classpath is the right solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Officially you can create a `var/lib/rundeck/lib` directory and put the latest driver there, take a [look](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#add-the-jdbc-driver).

Alternatively, you can clone the repo, [update the package](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/main/rundeckapp/build.gradle#L193), and [build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61553419/10426011) your "own" WAR. That WAR file can be saved on the `/var/lib/rundeck/bootstrap` path (RPM/DEB installations).

The source code references [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.4.0.jre8) package (pretty old, from 2018). You can update to the [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/11.2.0.jre8) and test, of course, this process is at your own risk.

Finally, you can suggest the driver update [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).